# Jetpack Compose: Get actual route of nav w/ arguments

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I want to retrieve the current route of my nav controller with arguments.
If i call `navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route`, i do not receive the arguments, but a placeholder like so: `chat/{id}`, whereas i would like `chat/127436112`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getString("yourArgumentName"))
```

to retrieve value of the argument.

Comment: Its not quite what i asked for, but it can be done with this code, so i marked it as accepted, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full solution to the question:

```
    private fun getRouteWithArguments(
        destination: NavDestination,
        arguments: Bundle?,
    ): String? {
        var route = destination.route
        arguments?.let { bundle ->
            destination.arguments.keys.forEach { key ->
                val value = destination.arguments[key]?.type?.get(bundle, key)?.toString() ?: "Null"
                route = route?.replaceFirst("{$key}", value)
            }
        }
        return route
    }
```